# How to edit wordpress page from mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, menu

I need help with one thing. I don't really know the Wordpress structure. I need query to show me id_pages  belong to menu that i want. Also i want to get content of that pages.

Comment: what you want to achieve through this? Maybe its already exists. Describe more about.

Comment: i have my own category/products mini-cms inside wordpress. i really need only that query.

Comment: (mini-cms) you means separate files and data in WordPress?

Comment: my own php code. i use same database as WP, so i can execute query and get that content of pages in menu that i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL query is not a good idea. You should use [WP tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags)

Comment: I use that in admin panel, so i think is secure.